# Restore a previous version of My Site pages

Tags: my-site, sharepoint-online

How can I restore a previous version of the mysite pages?

At some point during customisation, we made some major changes to the pages (particularly default.aspx) that we want to revert but I can't find the pages in either SPD or via all site content to revert them.

Answer (score 2):

**TRY THIS BELOW STEPS**

Go to Site page Location -> Click on **PAGE** ribbon -> Select **VERSIONS** option -> you will get **ALL VERSIONS** of the PAGE -> Then Click on **MODIFIED LINK** (Which version you want to RESTORE) and **RESTORE** Version.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way you can achieve this. You can View/Restore a particular webpage which either in Pages Library/SitePages as follows:

`SiteUrl/_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={ListId}&ID=ItemId`

- ListId : ID of pages library or Site pages
- ItemId : ID of particular page

Once you get the versions, you can select a particular version and restore it.

Assumption: You might have enabled versioning settings for the Page Library.

Comment: Any idea how I can get the ID of the page, given that it doesn't appear in site pages for the my sites?

Comment: To view the ID of the particular page, modify the view (/SitePages/Forms/AllPages.aspx) and set the 'ID' checkbox.

Comment: But the My Site pages don't appear in all site pages - otherwise I wouldn't have this problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can restore a particular page by doing this:

```
SiteUrl/_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={ListId}&ID=ItemId
```

The way to get the ListId is to call `_spPageContextInfo`

I would just go to the page, open console, and run `_spPageContextInfo`

You would see ListId, ListItemId, etc

Answer (score -1):

you can also restore a backup of the SharePoint database taken the day before you have made the changes, connect it to your SharePoint test/dev environment and then retrieve the needed page.

Regards.

Comment: Database restore wouldn't be an available option in SharePoint Online. While it is possible to request a restore from support, that would revert the entire site collection.